# java - string functions are not changing the input string

Tags: java, string, concatenation

Following is my code:

```
 class program{

    public static void main(String[]args){

    String str = new String("I like Java ");
    str.concat("the most");
    str.toUpperCase();
    str.replace("LIKE","LOVE");
    System.out.println(str);

        }
   }
```

As I expect the output should be as:

```
I LOVE JAVA THE MOST
```

But, It isn't showing an error but also not showing the expected output...Instead it is only showing the original string:

[image: cmd screen]

Am I missing something or may be is it something else?

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: PS 'new String' is not needed. Do `String str = "I like Java"` instead.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel what is meant by immutable? as far as I know strings are taken as object in java.

Comment: @krupalshah: that's when you use google. I just gave you the term 2 minutes ago, I don't think you have read up on it yet.

Comment: It means you cannot change change them once they have been created. You can only create new Strings from existing Strings. But read a bit on Java Strings, it's the most covered area you could think of.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel ok..I will search..and I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798403/string-is-immutable-what-exactly-is-the-meaning

Comment: @JeroenVannevel why my question is marked as duplicate? as I said I did not know about this 'immutable'.

Comment: @krupalshah: that doesn't make it any less of a duplicate. Don't take it personally but do take it as a sign that you should refine your searching before you ask a question. For example when I google for *"java string doesn't change"* I get the answer in each of the first few results.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I already searched and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330961/string-length-not-working-properly-in-java but was not helpful

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I am in danger of getting banned because of this question that was genuine and not the duplicate...m hopeless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class is immutable. This means that every method does not change the original `String` instance, but it creates a new object and returns it, but you are not saving their reference. You could do:

```
String str = "I like Java";
str = str.concat("the most");
str = str.toUpperCase();
str = str.replace("LIKE","LOVE");
```

Or even better:

```
String str = "I like Java"
    .concat("the most")
    .toUpperCase()
    .replace("LIKE","LOVE");
```

This works because the methods are returning new `String` objects, so you can concatenate them.

Now when you use `System.out.println(str);` the result will be `I LOVE JAVATHE MOST`
(*because you forgot the space when concatenating the two strings*).

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
str.replace("LIKE","LOVE");
```

returns a `String` that holds the answer that you want, which you throw away. One easy fix is to change the last line:

```
System.out.println(str.concat("the most").toUpperCase().replace("LIKE","LOVE"));
```

and delete the useless calls above it.